# Automator: Get filename

Tags: automator, automation, folder-action

I'm creating a folder action to display a notification when a new file is downloaded and would like the notification to display the filename. I can't figure out how to extract the filename of the downloaded file and pass it on to the variable.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

[image: Picture]

Transcript:

- **Folder action receives files and folders to** *Downloads*(default Folder Action script)
- **Run Applescript:**

  ```
  on run {input, parameters}
      tell application "Finder"
          set filename to name of file input
      end tell
  end run
  ```
- **Set value of Variable:** *fileName*
- **Ask for Confirmation:**
  **Title:** Alert! The file *fileName* has been downloaded!
  **Body:** A new file has downloaded

So if I add a file named "NewFile.png", I get:
[image: Example]

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use a "Display Notification" action, which would be less obtrusive.

Comment: That would work as well.